# Functional version of a specific martingale central limit theorem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, limit-theorems

I am looking for a functional version of Theorem 1b of [Heyde](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3213349). The result states:

> **Theorem** *(Theorem 1b in  [Heyde](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3213349))*: Suppose that $(M_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a square-integrable martingale with mean zero. Write $W_n^2 := \sum_{i=n}^\infty M_i^2$ and $s_n^2:= \mathbb{E}(W_n^2)$. Suppose that $s_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and in addition:
> \begin{align} a)& \quad \frac{1}{s_n^2} \sum_{k=n}^\infty M_k^2 \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1 \text{ in probability, and} \\ b)& \quad\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{s_n^2} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sup_{k \geq n} M_k^2 \right]=0. \end{align}
> Then we have the convergence in distribution as $n$ tends to infinity
> $$\frac{\sum_{i=n}^\infty M_i}{s_n} \implies \mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

---

**Context**: After some modification, the Theorem of Heyde allows to establish (under some technical assumptions) fluctuation results of the form $$ \frac{M_\infty - M_n}{s_n} \implies \mathcal{N}(0,1). $$ I require an invariance principle result of the above in order to investigate the possibility of Gaussian fluctuations of a stochastic process. It seems plausible that the above result can be generalised to yield convergence in the Skorokhod space $D([0, + \infty))$ to some Gaussian process with specified covariance matrix. I am hoping for a martingale CLT of the form: $$ \left( \frac{\Lambda_t-M_{ \lfloor nt \rfloor}}{a_n}, t \geq 0 \right) \implies \left( W_t, t \geq 0 \right),$$
where $W=(W_t, t \geq 0)$ is a Gaussian process and $(a_n)$ is some normalising sequence. Any reference would be appreciated.